# vertx.createHttpClient().getNow() not invoking the handler

Tags: java, testing, handler, vert.x

I have the following test method:

```
private Vertx vertx;

@Before
public void setUp(TestContext context) throws IOException {
    vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    vertx.deployVerticle(MainVerticle.class.getName(), context.asyncAssertSuccess());
}

@After
public void tearDown(TestContext context) {
    vertx.close(context.asyncAssertSuccess());
}

@Test
public void serverIsStarted(TestContext context) {
    vertx.createHttpClient().getNow(8080, "localhost", "/inexistent", response -> {
        System.out.println("Handler running");
        Assert.assertEquals(response.statusCode(), 200);
        context.assertEquals(response.statusCode(), 200);
    });
    System.out.println("Done");
}
```

Taken from [this sample repo](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-gradle-starter). However, it doesn't really do anything. The path `inexistent` doesn't exist, and even if I remove the code that launches the server in `setUp`, the test still passes. Also the text "Handler running" is not printed, only "Done".

What am I missing, why doesn't it do anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remember that the request is being handled asynchronously. what you are experiencing is the tests running to completion before the asynchronous callback with the result can be handled.

per the [docs](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-unit/java/#_asynchronous_testing), what you should instead do is create an `Async` instance to signal to the test runner to keep the test running until `complete()` is called on that `Async` instance, like so:

```
@Test
public void serverIsStarted(TestContext context) {
    final Async async = context.async(); // <-- create the Async instance

    vertx.createHttpClient().getNow(8080, "localhost", "/inexistent", response -> {
        context.assertEquals(200, response.statusCode());

        async.complete();  // <-- signal this test can now terminate
    });
}
```

also, fyi - you have your parameters to `assertEquals()` backwards:

- the 1st parameter is the expected value
- the 2nd parameter is the actual value

hope that helps!